# Where is metamask's provider?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am trying to understand how MetaMask works in browser.

Metamask, as a browser extension, is used to send transactions for ethereum blockchain. After reading some articles, I think one of important things Metamask does is to inject a `Web3` instance into the browser's global variable `window` so that DApp's script could find a provider to make JSON_RPC call.

In `web3` instance, there is a `currentProvider` already defined by MetaMask. I am wondering where this `currentProvider` pointing to.

I develop and test my own dApp based on a my local private chain so I have an IP and port to create a HttpProvider to allow Dapp to connect to. But I don't know what is the IP and Port used by MetaMask to create a provider.

My questions:
1. Is there a server or cluster set up by MetaMask itself in order to receive transactions from MetaMask browser extension?
2. If no, what mechanism for MetaMask to get active node?
3. Can you provide source code for this part? There are too many projects under metamask so that I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metamask uses [Infura](https://infura.io/) as you can see here:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/5f3f8c85fcc5bd378ef1a886434a3e98546fee7f/app/scripts/controllers/network/enums.js

EDIT: It seems they have made some changes and now they are using this package: https://github.com/kumavis/eth-json-rpc-infura